# Flip-flop with a single strap over the front of the foot

Tags: single-word-requests

Wikipedia says on flip-flops http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flops:

"1. They consist of a flat sole held loosely on the foot by a Y-shaped strap that passes between the first and second toes and around either side of the foot. 2. They may also be held to the foot with a single strap over the front of the foot rather than a thong."

I would like to know a word for flip-flops for which 2 holds, but 1 does not. I suppose it cannot be a sandal since a sandal can have more than a single strap. It is also my requirement that the front is open, i.e. the strap does not cover the toes.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's no strap that goes between the toes, it can be called a flip-flop.

Comment: Do you mean a *sandal*?  There are many types of sandals, but I would definitely call one where "2 held, but 1 did not" a sandal.

Comment: @Jim A sandal can have more than a single strap. I require a single strap.

Comment: @dt1510 - Yes, that's true, but it doesn't mean that what you've described isn't a sandal. A word to describe a building where a family lives with 4 bedrooms and 2 baths is a house even though a house can also have more than 4 bedrooms

Comment: @Jim But I would like to know a word with as little ambiguity as possible. If I say to somebody to buy me sandals (meaning the shoes I described), I do not want them to bring me sandals with more than one strap. Of course, I could always explain, but this is a one word request question.

Comment: @dt1510 Yes, a full, detailed explanation in that case would be best.  I don't think I'd risk my future satisfaction for the sake of a one-word request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word for ones that satisfy only condition two appears to be "Slide Sandals" according to marketing text by brooks brothers, adidas, nike, etc. The "Slide" part obviously comes from the fact that you don't have to reach down to put them on like traditional sandals, instead you just slide a foot in.

[Example](http://www.brooksbrothers.com/Leather-Slide-Sandals/797F________DKBR_10___D___,default,pd.html?CMP=bac_us_google_pla_P_P_M_PLA_Mens&gclid=CjgKEAjwwuqcBRCSuoivmIPnkwQSJACpqj3kMM-npgzGMw2pSHFmoANEBNpehCbPD07eG2b1h7yzi_D_BwE)

Comment: The questioner is not confused. They are asking if there is a word that describes flip-flops satisfying definition #2, but excludes the ones that satisfy definition #1.

Comment: @phenry I see, changed my answer.

Comment: 'Slip-on sandals' would be my suggestion for the same concept.  Yours seems to have a higher proportion of conforming images in Google search ;)

Answer (score 1):

A type of shoe which allows the foot to slide into without the need for buckles or laces is typically called a **[mule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_%28shoe%29)**. The ***mule sandal*** has recently made a sort of comeback especially among women. One of the simplest mule sandals I found was the following:

[image]

> Mules experienced some popularity in the 1950s and early 1960s, and
>   were seen in 1970s almost exclusively in the form of open-back
>   Scandinavian clogs, but then re-emerged in the early 1990s, **especially
>   in its open-toed form** (the "slide"), and began to dominate the shoe market for women.

Another type of strap sandal, usually more favoured by men are ***[Jesus sandals](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=men%27s%20%22jesus%20sandals%22&oq=men%27s%20%22jesus%20sandals%22&gs_l=img.12...6490.14376.0.16129.6.6.0.0.0.0.145.710.0j6.6.0....0...1c.1.46.img..6.0.0.ds1R4vh62Tk)*** which will often have two straps, with or without buckles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to [strap sandals](https://www.google.it/search?q=strap%20sandal&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ieKbU-nbM4mO7Aa674C4Aw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=667&bih=806#imgrc=AFh0uOyRnaUE1M%253A;5AkooL0F-2OLzM;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.xojane.co.uk%252Ffiles%252Fsites%252Fdefault%252Ffiles%252Fimagecache%252Farticle_full_width%252Ffield_image_attachments%252Farticle%252FHOUPLA-Leather-Strap-Sandal.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.xojane.co.uk%252Fclothes%252Fall-i-want-simple-pair-sandals-too-much-ask;460;360).

Comment: Your link diminishes your answer considerably, showing everything from flip flops to stiletto heels!